# Woocommerce Check-out Customer Condition

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

On the checkout page in woocommerce, I have provided a distinction between provinces and districts, but when the customer chooses the district, I want to assign an ID that I have previously specified to the database. I want it to print the county directly in the form of a string. Where do I write the if?

Example -> billing_adress (Okayama) to i want database write Customer country (OK8299)

Briefly; I want to register in customer country with a different ID. Not with the country name. How can i do?

Please help me thank you

Database Screenshot suit_**wc_customer_lookup**
[image: wc_customer_lookup database]

As you can see, "seyhan" is writing. I want instead of "TR.00100TR". I want to complete this data by putting in excel and if else. I would be very happy if you help. For example, if Seyhan is city TR.00100TR, if Ceyhan is city TR.00102TR.

Thanks

Comment: Your  provided details are not enough clear (or detailed)… How you are providing the distinction between provinces and districts? What is that ID (In what database table?) that you want to assign? Are you using some custom related code yet? If yes you should provide it in your question… Also we expect you to provide in your question your own real code attempt, even if it is incomplete and/or doesn't work.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec  I edited. All I want is to write the ID I set into the database if seyhan is selected in the address section. Id's in excel. Thank you